# Div center align not working with 2 floated elements

Tags: html, css

Im trying to center align a div that has, property overflow:hidden and 2 children elements which are floated, inside another parent container.

This is the strucuture --

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="help"> 
    <div class="icon"></div> 
    <div class="help-text"> 
      <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      </div> 
      <div>In aliquet <strong>malesuada faucibus</strong</div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>


.container{
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.help{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon{
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQItU_j6F-zWMlDkRQIhwjnEe9Jm4F-liLYlx1Y6cuLLiqfdGDmdQ) no-repeat;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.help-text{
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Here, the contents inside div.help are supposed to be center aligned. div.icon and div.help-text are floated. To fix float break their parent div.help has overflow-hidden.

JSBin link -- http://jsbin.com/tahak/3/

Issue is, its always left aligned. I want to center align it. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You should really close that unclosed `<strong>` tag...

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: inline-block` to following class:

```
.help{
  /*overflow: hidden; You can remove this*/
  display: inline-block;/*Add this*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1f7d93rf/2/)

Comment: +1 Nice catch. Note that there's no need to use `overflow: hidden;` anymore in this case. Safely remove it.

Comment: **This is not at all a solution:**  *"the contents inside div.help are supposed to be center aligned"*. this center aligns `.help` itself, not it's content.

Comment: I think that's OP ask.. This align `.help` and children elements. Dunno why you don't find this as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

actually, can you briefly describe what needs to be centered?Everything you have inside your div is floated to left.So what do you want to be centered.

------or---
do you want something like this---
[image: JSbin Edit by sarthak]

Comment: @goose.You should tell what exactly you want as you seem little bit unclear.Is that pic above is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

text-align is not the solution,
first, the div you wanted to center doesnt have a defined width, so it will automatically set as width: 100%

so you need to add
    width: 50%

and to make it to center
   margin: auto;

Answer (score 0):

> the contents inside div.help are supposed to be center aligned

As you can see below:

```
<div class="help"> 
   <div class="icon"></div> 
   <div class="help-text"> 
     <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
     </div> 
     <div>
       In aliquet <strong>malesuada faucibus</strong
     </div> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

The only contents inside `.help` is `div.icon` and `div.help-text` inside .

> div.icon and div.help-text are floated

So obviously there is nothing else to be center aligned.

Answer (score 0):

```
.help{
  overflow: hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

mention display: inline block for .help block.

it works fine.